# Is there a difference between 'a' and 'de' when the meaning is 'from'?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, word-comparison, preposition, differences

The Latin preposition *de* takes an ablative object and has several different translations including 'about', 'of', 'down from' and 'from'. The preposition *a*/*ab* also has multiple meanings including 'after', 'by' and 'from'.

Both words can mean 'from'. When the meaning of the word is 'from', is there a difference in usage or meaning and is it preferable to use one over the other?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Interesting question; I want to see a thorough answer to this one.

Comment: Random hypothesis (in case it is worth as a lead for anyone's research): it might have to do with them being applicable to different categories of places, like in Italian _in_ vs _a_, or (arguably) in Englis _in_, _on_, _at_.

Comment: @Rafael Interesting... I don't know any Italian - what's the difference between _in_ and _a_?

Comment: @LJD200 Not an expert, but you use _in_ for countries and rooms, while _a_ for (specific) cities and buildings. (natural question: what happens with city-states?---I don't know)

Comment: @Rafael.Italian a is from ad, not ab, so it is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @fdb It doesn't have to come from the same word - it just illustrates that the Latin words could be applicable to different categories of places like words in some other languages.

Answer (score 6):

Like all good questions, this one has no simple answer.  The big dictionaries devote many columns to it.  Kennedy 286 gives a crisp & useful summary. A couple of firm examples:

1. Travelling **from** a place... is ***ab***.
2. I am of or **from** the family X... is ***de***.

Nearly always, *ab* is elided to *a* before a consonant.  See the Oxford Latin Dictionary for exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

*A place-holder,* until someone writes the perfect answer.  Rule of thumb rules:

Avoid an elision or a hiatus by choosing *'ab,' 'abs',* in preference to *'a'* or *'de.'*

> ab urbe.

Where 'from' can be replaced by 'down from', pick *'de'*

> de montibus cucurrit. de turris autem versus concino.