# Translation of ab and de in Greek,

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, greek, etymology, language-evolution

How would one best translate ab and de from Latin to Greek in order to capture the different nuances?

In Greek both are usually translated as από.

I am trying to capture the nuances so I am using etymology but I always get told that I commit to the Etymological fallacy.

Comment: Related: [Is there a difference between 'a' and 'de' when the meaning is 'from'?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/is-there-a-difference-between-a-and-de-when-the-meaning-is-from)

Comment: Since I don't mind the etymological fallacy too much, consideringing homonym, polysemous German *ab*, comparing *anti*, *ago*, and eventually considering below allusions to Aristotle, I want to mention *category* (uncertain ety, how interesting) and recommend *kata*. I do mind enough not to post that as an answer. Just note that modern *apo* translates as *runter* ~ "down, off" in various cases (off of the horse, even *runter vom Platz* "off of the palazo"). Also Cp *derivation*, *aberration*.

Comment: @vectory But κατά would always mean against. Καταγωγή would always mean the origin. Απαγωγή could be abduction or deduction but Καταγωγή would be(and currently is) origin.

Comment: Wiktionary glosses "[2. (*with accusative*)] 6. according to", thus cp *de legis*. I was chiefly refering to *kata, kato* "down", anyhow, unaware of *against*. That does not fit very well (and my, err, derivation is a non-secitur). But since *de* is highly polysemous, I should think the question is not narrow enough?

Answer (score 2):

The two alternative forms **Ἀθήνηθεν** and **ἀπὸ Άθηνῶν** have been virtually interchangeable, as you may ascertain from a diachronic text search.  St Paul used the latter, of course, but would *never* use the former -- too archaic. The further back you go, the more the former predominates (down to Ἀθήνῃθεν).

That is to say the primary two meanings of ἀπό:

- motion away from
- origin of all kinds

but not

- far from
- after time, since,

seem to be accessed by both words, and appear to not follow the Latin usage split linked in the comment, such as it might well have been...

Comment: What were the words used by Aristotle for Abduction and Deduction respectively then? Did he use Απαγωγή; Did he use Επαγωγή;

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. If you gave me exact passages, I'd run to them, and so might you.  I *believe* from memory, the Alexandrian mathematicians, and current practice (!), that his Ἐπαγωγή  got translated to Inductio and his  Ἀπαγωγή to Reductio. Will scan the TLG and Perseus.

Comment: Arist.APr.69a20: ἡ εἰς τὸ ἀδύνατον ἀπαγωγή : reductio per impossibile .   In the Logic of Aristotle, ἐπαγωγή: argument by induction.

Comment: Further facts (best available): A's  ἀπαγωγή is also translated as abduction; it is his συλλογισμός that gets translated to deduction. Aristotle and his translations have swirled around long enough to render any linguistic systematic correspondence moot, here.  Are you perhaps more interested in Aristotelian terminology or in the usage of -θεν  vs.  ἀπό ?

Comment: Neither. I am interesented in a correspondence( which has been rendered moot) and 2 distinct words to capture the diferent nuances of ab and de(which as you told me don't exist there is no single word distinction in greek between motion away from and origin of all kinds). If anything I would lean towards Aristotelian terminology though.